# Displaying object's data

Tags: php

How can I make the `$validation` false, I tried this but it will never return false to me.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // starting date post data
    $startDay = $_POST['startDay'];
    $startMonth = $_POST['startMonth'];
    $startYear = $_POST['startYear'];

    // ending date post data
    $endDay = $_POST['endDay'];
    $endMonth = $_POST['endMonth'];
    $endYear = $_POST['endYear'];

    // team post data
    $team = $_POST['selectTeam'];
    $validation = true;

    if ($validation) {
        if (!isset($startDay) || $startDay === 'defaultDay') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($startMonth) || $startMonth === 'defaultMonth') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($startYear) || $startYear === 'defaultYear') {   
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($endDay) || $endDay === 'defaultDay') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($endMonth) || $endMonth === 'defaultMonth') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($endYear) || $endYear === 'defaultYear') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if (!isset($team) || $team === 'defaultTeam') {
            $validation = false;
        }

        if ($validation=true) {
            echo 'testing';
        } elseif ($validation=false) {
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is

```
if ($validation = true) {
    echo 'testing';
} else if ($validation = false) {
    echo 'false';
}
```

change it to

```
if ($validation === true) {
    echo 'testing';
} else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: just use `ELSE` if there is no more option...

Comment: Thanks, it works. Appreciate :)

Comment: in that case accept answer please so others don't waste time answering this question :-)

Comment: he is so excited bro @perdeep singh ...forgot to accept the answer...hahaha...

Comment: lol yeah that happens